# "Positionieren" - Dativ oder Akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case

Wie erfragt man richtig – wird *wohin* (so wie mit „gestellt“) oder *wo* positioniert?

> Die Wortstellung wird invertiert und das Verb wird ... Satzanfang
>   positioniert.

*An den* Satzanfang oder *am* Satzanfang?

Ich neige zum Akkusativ, bin mir aber nicht sicher.

Comment: Herzlich willkommen bei German.Stackexchange! Dankesformeln sind hier nicht üblich, daher habe ich deine Antwort editert. Wir sind alle hier, weil wir Fragen haben oder gerne Klugscheißen ;)

Comment: +1 für obigen Kommentar wegen des "... weil wir gerne Klugscheißen" :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analog zum [Duden-Beispiel](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/positionieren):

> einen Satelliten im Weltraum positionieren

würde ich den Dativ verwenden:

> Die Wortstellung wird invertiert und das Verb wird **am** Satzanfang positioniert.

Answer (score 3):

Beides ist möglich, abhängig davon, ob es dir um die Bewegung (also das Verschieben an den Satzanfang = Akkusativ) oder das Ergebnis (dass das Verb hinterher am Anfang steht = Dativ) geht - Die Verwendung von Dativ oder Akkusativ bei Wechselpräpositionen wie "an" entscheidet sich also danach, ob *Richtung* oder *Lage* spannend sind. Da das bei deinem Beispielsatz mehr oder weniger auf dasselbe herauskommt, kannst du wählen.

Comment: Etwas *dorthin* zu positionieren ist zwar grammatikalisch nicht falsch, aber doch reichlich unüblich.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Sucht man nach Fundstellen für *positionieren*, findet man überwiegend weder Verwendung mit Dativ noch Akkusativ, sondern eher eine reflexive.